# Error when trying to render a tagged string literal

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, string-literals, tagged-templates

I'm fetching some data from an API , then for each element returned I'm running this code:

```
fetch("./apifiles.json").then((res) => res.json()).then((users) => {
        users.usuarios.forEach(e => {

            var div = document.createElement("DIV");

            content = `<h5>usuario:</h5> ${e.name} 
            <h5>id: </h5>${e.id}
            `;

            div.append(content)
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        });
    })
```

I was expecting the browser to understand and parse the HTML tags inside de "content" variable, however this is what I get in the browser:

```
<h5>usuario:</h5> srth <h5>id: </h5>0
<h5>usuario:</h5> mthaz <h5>id: </h5>1
<h5>usuario:</h5> oatrz <h5>id: </h5>2
```

Clearly there is something I'm doing wrong. What can I do so that the browser understands the HTML tags and format it as I expect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add it as `innerHTML` to div

```js
let e = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'some name'
}

var div = document.createElement("DIV");

let content = `<h5>usuario:</h5> ${e.name} 
        <h5>id: </h5>${e.id}
        `;

div.innerHTML = content
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `div.append(content)`, use `div.innerHTML = content`.

Append is used for DOM, not for strings.

Comment: You can use `.append` for strings, DOM nodes, or a mix of the two [(see mdn ref).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) `.appendChild` is DOM-node only. `.innerHTML` attempts to parse the text it is assigned as HTML/XML depending on doctype, while `.append` just creates a Text node out of it, regardless of whether or not it might contain valid markup that could be parsed to generate elements for the document.